# Local Drupal 7 user in database

Tags: database

I want to save a user's email and username when a button is clicked.
I assume I have to do this via PHP but I can find the user column at localhost/phpmyadmin. Where is the users' information being stored and which is the MySQL query to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a direct MySQL query to update anything.

In this case you can use [user_save();](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) which it is basically, load the user `object -> change` `data -> pass` it to `user_save()`; or even better user [entityAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) and [entity_metadata_wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers)

The default table where drupal saves user data is `users`, there you can find the email and username